# Table in itemize

Tags: tables, itemize, tabu

Is it possible to include a table in itemize?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\begin{tabu}[X X]
\toprule
150 & 150 \\ bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
```

The alignment should be:

- Item 1

  ---

  150    150

  ---
- Item 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add *complete* examples with the necessary packages.

You're using the wrong syntax for the table. Column specifiers should be within braces (`{}`) not brackets (`[]`). To get the alignment you want, just add an empty line after `item`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1

\begin{tabu}{X X}
\toprule
150 & 150 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\item item 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, `\begin{tabu}{l l}` more close to desired output.

Comment: @ferahfeza Perhaps, but the `X` columns came from the OPs code.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. Will remember to give complete code next time onwards. My error was NOT leaving a line between \item and \begin{tabu}

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
\item item 1\par
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X}
\toprule
150 & 150 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]